# Can linecache be used for concurrent reading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, batch-processing, spacy

I want to read and process a file by using multiprocessing with low memory consumption, high throughput (sentence/s), and - especially important - ordered results.

I was wondering whether we can use linecache's `getline` for this purpose. The following code reads a file, hopefully in parallel, and executes some function on the lines that are gathered in the subprocess. Here I opted for running some tokenisation on the files with spaCy.

```py
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
from os import cpu_count
from pathlib import Path
from functools import partial
from linecache import getline

import spacy


class Processor:
    def __init__(self, spacy_model='en_core_web_sm', batch_size=2048):
        self.nlp = spacy.load(spacy_model, disable=['ner', 'textcat'])
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    @staticmethod
    def get_n_lines(pfin):
        with pfin.open(encoding='utf-8') as fhin:
            for line_idx, _ in enumerate(fhin, 1):
                pass

        return line_idx

    def process_file(self, fin):
        pfin = Path(fin).resolve()
        total_lines = self.get_n_lines(pfin)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

        procfunc = partial(self.process_batch, pfin)
        with Pool(cpu_count() - 1) as pool:
            # map the starting indexex to the processes
            for _ in pool.imap(procfunc, range(0, total_lines+1, self.batch_size)):
                pass

        print('done', (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds())

    def process_batch(self, pfin, start):
        lines = [getline(str(pfin), i) for i in range(start, start+self.batch_size)]

        # Parse text with spaCy
        docs = list(self.nlp.pipe(lines))

        # Chop into sentences
        spacy_sents = [str(sent) for doc in docs for sent in doc.sents]

        return str(current_process()), spacy_sents


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = r'data/train.tok.low.en'
    proc = Processor()
    proc.process_file(fn)
```

I found that on my work laptop, running with 3 active cores on a file of 140K sentences the duration is 261 seconds. When running with a single core (`n_workers=1`), the processing time is 431 seconds. I am not sure how to interpret this difference but I guess it comes down to the question: does `linecache.getline` allow for concurrent reading? Parallel execution *s* faster, but considering `getline` expects a *file name* (rather than a file object), I expect it to have to open the file every time and as such blocking access for other processes. Is this assumption correct because parallel execution still seems much faster? Is there a better way to read files fast and in parallel whilst also keeping the results ordered?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need linecache, and it doesn't help.

First, you don't need any special tricks to read the same file simultaneously from multiple processes. You can just do it. It'll work.

Second, linecache loads a whole file immediately as soon as a single line is requested from that file. You're not splitting the work of reading the file at all. You're doing *more* I/O than if you just had the parent process read the file and let the workers inherit the data. If you're getting any speedup from multiprocessing, it's probably due to parallelizing the NLP work, not the file reading.

Third, linecache is designed to support the `traceback` module, and it does a lot of stuff that doesn't make sense for a general-purpose file reading module, including searching the import path for a file if it doesn't find the file in the current directory.

Comment: From my testing, reading the file in the main process line by line (not as bytes but as unicode strings) is actually slower. That is not a huge surprise I guess since reading 'lines' is relatively slow, and if you have multiple processes (say 48) your main process will never be able to keep up with the workers available. Reading files as byte chunks works well but you'll have to deal with incomplete lines that you need to stitch back together.